# User to access SharePoint 2010 Subsite only (Vendor Problem?)

Tags: permissions, access-denied

I have:

SP2010 rented from a company. 1 site collection

I have many subsites, however it has come to a time whereby we need only a few people to access 1 specific sub site e.g.

Company > USA > Marketing

So, Marketing is a subsite of USA which is a subsite of Company.

To make a user **ONLY** view the marketing subsite I must:

- Stop the inheritance from USA site
- Give the appropriate user DIRECT PERMISSION to the Marketing subsite

The above is basic stuff. I set it all up and when the user tries to access the subsite the get an error message. "Error: Access Denied". I have called and email support and they are saying it is complicated matter and that they are investigating.

My question:

I have a rented site collection from a company (Apps4rent). However, they are having difficulties in trying to do the above as it seem something complicated.

Is it possible there is a problem with the company or am I missing something here?

Here is the code for Home.aspx

```
    oint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"       %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/> - 
    <SharePoint:ListItemProperty runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <span>
        <SharePoint:DocumentFolderName runat="server" id="PageFolderName" AppendSeparatorArrow = "true"/>
    </span>
    <span class="ms-WikiPageNameEditor-Display" id="wikiPageNameDisplay" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:ListItemProperty runat="server"/>
    </span>
    <span class="ms-WikiPageNameEditor-Edit" style="display:none;" id="wikiPageNameEdit" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox id="wikiPageNameEditTextBox" runat="server"/>
    </span>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent runat="server" UIVersion="4">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Description" runat="server"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:AlphaImage ID=onetidtpweb1 Src="/_layouts/images/wiki.png" Width=145 Height=54 Alt="" Runat="server"/></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <meta name="CollaborationServer" content="SharePoint Team Web Site" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var navBarHelpOverrideKey = "WSSEndUser";
    </script>
    <SharePoint:RssLink runat="server"/>
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" Name="wiki.css" />
    </ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMiniConsole" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:FormComponent TemplateName="WikiMiniConsole" ControlMode="Display" runat="server" id="WikiMiniConsole"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:RecentChangesMenu runat="server" id="RecentChanges"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent runat="server" UIVersion="3" Id="PlaceHolderWebDescription">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="ms-webpartpagedescription"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Description" runat="server"/></div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
    <asp:UpdatePanel
           id="updatePanel"
           runat="server"
           UpdateMode="Conditional"
           ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <SharePoint:VersionedPlaceHolder UIVersion="4" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonButton
                    id="btnWikiEdit"
                    RibbonCommand="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit.Menu.SaveEdit.Edit"
                    runat="server"
                    Text="edit"/>
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonButton
                    id="btnWikiSave"
                    RibbonCommand="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit.Menu.SaveEdit.SaveAndStop"
                    runat="server"
                    Text="edit"/>
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonButton
                    id="btnWikiRevert"
                    RibbonCommand="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit.Menu.SaveEdit.Revert"
                    runat="server"
                    Text="Revert"/>
            </SharePoint:VersionedPlaceHolder>
            <SharePoint:EmbeddedFormField id="WikiField" FieldName="WikiField" ControlMode="Display" runat="server"><div class="ExternalClass44E19850FE3C4C8394B62A00300331C0"><table id="layoutsTable" style="width:100%"><tbody><tr style="vertical-align:top"><td style="width:66.6%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width:100%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><h1 class="ms-rteElement-H1B" style="margin-bottom:0px"><span><span>
        PIB</span></span></h1>
<p>This section of the sites looks at content production &amp; script production for 
the Teleprompter<br /></p></div></div></td>
<td style="width:33.3%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width:100%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><br />
<div id="vid_e82c931e-53ac-4043-9c42-a207770c2a1f" style="display:none"></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
<span id="layoutsData" style="display:none">false,false,2</span></div></SharePoint:EmbeddedFormField>
            <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="Bottom" Title="loc:Bottom"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="WikiField" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnWikiRevert" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnWikiSave" />
    </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I have the same issue in my company! I have a group that must access a subsite, but cannot access the main site. I use the same templates, images, etc. I spent 2 weeks trying to figure it out the I found your response! Thank you so much!! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If your site uses custom branding or scripts, those items are usually placed in the /Style Library/ of the root site.  In your example, the user might be attempting to open /sites/USA/Marketing but that is in turn attempting to reference resources in /Style Library/ which the user might not have permissions to, thus access denied.

Comment: You are right. There was a logo that was on the home page and was connected to the home page. I have deleted it but I get the same error.... Is there any way to find out if there are assets coming from other  site/libraries.

Comment: In order to get the "Access Denied" message, it has to be a server-side request, which would mean that you need to look at the source of any custom master pages, page layouts, and even web parts and look for server-side inclusion of resources outside of the secured site

Comment: Ok... I think you are right...I have created a new site without my template and it works. When I use my template I get the error message. I have access all the viewlsts.aspx and other stuff. However when I access the home.aspx I get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct process.  You have to make sure you are giving them the url directly to the Marketing subsite.

I suppose there could be something complex going on if we're talking about forms/claims based authentication they have to sort out.

Comment: It is just basic access to view a few docs and maybe a discussion board. Nothing complicated. I am wondering if there is an issue with the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - here is what I found:

You need to add "Read" to your permission levels, then the "access denied" dissapears.

The user will be able to access this subsite, but nothing else - this is what you wanted, I gather.